# why can't I use TypeTag instead of ClassTag -Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand this piece of code

```
def myFunc[A:ClassTag](seq: A*) = {

println("The array representation is "+ Array[A](seq: _*))  }

myFunc(Seq(1,2),Seq(3,4,5,6))
myFunc("a","b","c")
```

I have a couple of questions regarding this :-

1. Why can't I use TypeTag instead of ClassTag here?
2. Am I correct in saying that myFunc takes in variable number of some generic types and returns an Array of variable number of generic type ( this doesn't make sense, but why does the code mean that way?)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because the `Array` object's `apply` method specifically requires a `ClassTag` and not a `TypeTag`. [Here's the documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array$.html#apply[T](xs:T*)(implicitevidence$2:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):Array[T]). Arrays only need the `ClassTag` information, and I believe the class predates `TypeTag` anyway.
2. Your code does not return the array, it merely prints it. If you changed it to return the array, you could say it takes in a variable number of instances of some generic type (one single type per invocation), and returns an array of elements of that type.